# $42$ degrees is constructible, how do I show? At the same line, how do I show that $18$ degrees has $\cos$ constructible?

Tags: abstract-algebra, trigonometry

I am working with constructible numbers and there are some questions that I could not solve.
For example, I have to show that $42$ degrees is constructible. On way of do this is using that it has $\cos$ and $\sin$ constructible, but I just can't find a way to show this.

Could someone help me?

At the same line, how do I show that at least the $\cos$ is constructible, for example, in the case we are working with $18$ degrees. Once I show this, using $\sin^2(18) + \cos^2(18)$ the claim holds because if $18$ is constructible then, $\sin (18)$ is constructible if, and only if $\cos(18)$ is.

Comment: I mean "constructible" the number who admits a construction by rule and straightedge.

Comment: HINT: show that $\cos(42^{\circ})=\frac{1}{4} \sqrt{\frac{1}{2} \left(5+\sqrt{5}\right)}-\frac{1}{8} \sqrt{3}
   \left(1-\sqrt{5}\right)$

Comment: HINT: $42$ is the sum of $21+21$

Comment: see also here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_constants_expressed_in_real_radicals#42.C2.B0:_sum_21.C2.B0_.2B_21.C2.B0

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner nice! But my problem is exactly this: How do I show that $\cos (42)$ has this expression?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From a regular hexagon, $60^\circ$ is constructible. From a regular pentagon, $72^\circ$ is constructible. Hence is the difference $12^\circ$. Multiply by $4$ to find $48^\circ$, then subtract from $90^\circ$ to find $42^\circ$.

Start from a pentagon ($72^\circ$) and half the angle twice to arrive at $18^\circ$.

Comment: Nice approach!
For the second part we get: $72 = 4.18$ and once $72$ is constructible, so $18$ is. This is right?